# all possible sub strings matching the regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string

```
<start><tag1><tag2><tag3><end>
```

if I have a regex `<.*end>` it matches the complete string and stops. Is there some way so that it gives all the matching substrings ike

```
<end>
<tag3><end>
<tag2><tag3><end>
<tag1><tag2><tag3><end>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you must wrap your pattern in a lookahead (this is the only way to obtain overlapped results):

```
(?=(<.*end>))
```

The result is in the capture group 1.

Answer (score 2):

Use a lookahead assertion to find the matches.

It's often a good idea to avoid strictly zero width expressions, so add sub expression outside the assertion to gobble a single character.

```
(?=(<.*<end>)).
```

Demonstrated below:

```
my $string = '<start><tag1><tag2><tag3><end>';

while ($string =~ /(?=(<.*end>))./g) {
    print $1, "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
<start><tag1><tag2><tag3><end>
<tag1><tag2><tag3><end>
<tag2><tag3><end>
<tag3><end>
<end>
```

Comment: It is, but it isn't strictly necessary in this case.  Overall, I definitely advise people to avoid using zero width expressions though, as they'll often behave in ways people don't expect.

Comment: Using only zero width expressions is not a problem if you keep in mind that the regex engine after each try will advance and if you want to obtain something you need a capturing group.